# Jquery Validate Max Method With a Dynamic Value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I tried the script of http://jqueryvalidation.org/max-method/.. with examples of static values. how to use the max value but dynamic? 
I tried with this script but it did not work

```js
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      max: "#field1" //from field1 dynamic value???
    //max: 23 //static value
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
    <lable>value1 : </lable>
    <input type="text" class="left" id="field1" name="field1"><br>
    <lable>no greater than value1 : </lable>
    <input type="text" class="left" id="field" name="field">
      <br/>
<input type="submit" value="Validate!">
</form>
```

how to work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Return the value of the field using a function.

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
    rules: {
        field: {
            required: true,
            max: function() {
                return parseInt($('#field1').val());
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Remember to enclose the value within `parseInt` or the number could be evaluated as a string.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/dq7wf3qj/**

Answer (score 0):

set max as `max: function(){ return $("#field1").val();}`

```js
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
    max: function(){ return $("#field1").val();}
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
    <lable>value1 : </lable>
    <input type="text" class="left" id="field1" name="field1"><br>
    <lable>no greater than value1 : </lable>
    <input type="text" class="left" id="field" name="field">
      <br/>
<input type="submit" value="Validate!">
</form>
```