# Can I use .val that will serve as my MAXLENGHT in my validation?

Tags: html, jquery

Considering  the first input tag will serve as the **MAX** value for validation:

```
 <input type="number" name="tp"  id="tp" class="form-control" readonly="readonly">
```

And the second input where I will input a value that should be greater than or not less than 1:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="u_payment" name="u_payment" required>
```

Here's my jQuery validation;

```
        $( "#reg" ).validate( {
        rules: {
            u_payment: {
                required: true,
                digits: true,
                max: $('#tp').val(),
                min:1,
            }   
        },
        errorElement: "em",
        errorPlacement: function ( error, element ) {
            error.addClass( "help-block" );
            element.parents( ".u_val" ).addClass( "has-feedback" );

            if ( element.prop( "type" ) === "checkbox" ) {
                error.insertAfter( element.parent( "label" ) );
            } else {
                error.insertAfter( element );
            }
            if ( !element.next( "span" )[ 0 ] ) {
                $( "<span class=\'form-control-feedback\'></span>" ).insertAfter( element );
            }
        },
        success: function ( label, element ) {
            if ( !$( element ).next( "span" )[ 0 ] ) {
                $( "<span class=\' form-control-feedback\'></span>" ).insertAfter( $( element ) );
            }
        },
        highlight: function ( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
            $( element ).parents( ".u_val" ).addClass( "has-error" ).removeClass( "has-success" );
        },
        unhighlight: function ( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
            $( element ).parents( ".u_val" ).addClass( "has-success" ).removeClass( "has-error" );
        }
    } );
```

Is it possible in **MAX** I can assign it using this `$('#tp').val()` that will serve as the MAX value for my validation? or there's other way do it?
Thank you!!

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32883244/jquery-validate-max-method-with-a-dynamic-value) post ?

Comment: @Swati sorry for late reply was busy on school stuff. I'm so glad for this post thank you much swati for helping me.

Comment: @Swati is there any way that if I check the checkboxes it will automatically validate? in my case i need to click the input field 'tp' for it to validate

Comment: I have not tried but , you can write on change event on checkbox and if its checked you can trigger `click` event on your `tp` input box .